# What is the role of ResourceServlet in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to know the exact role of `RessourceServlet`.
I've read many topics, but it's still not clear.
This is my code in web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Resource</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resource</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/combo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ResourceServlet` has many benefits, including the ability to serve files from within a jar in your classpath and the ability to provide a default resource when the desired resource is not available. For complete details, the JavaDoc is well-documented: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ResourceServlet.html